# Can't install nodejs on CentOS 7 using epel-release

Tags: node.js, centos7

So something strange happened this week and I'm not sure if it's only me. When I create a new EC2 instance with CentOS 7 from the Marketplace ( CentOS 7 (x86_64) - with Updates HVM ) and I try to install nodejs I am getting the error that nodejs package is not found. Of course prior to installing nodejs I am installing epel-release as nodejs is a part of this package.

Error output bellow:

```
    [root@ip-172-31-15-245 centos]# yum install epel-release -y`

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
* base: download.cf.centos.org
* extras: download.cf.centos.org
* updates: download.cf.centos.org
base                                                                                                                                                                                          | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                                                                                                        | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                                                       | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
(1/4):  extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                            | 243 kB  00:00:00
(2/4):  base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                                                                | 153 kB  00:00:00
(3/4):  updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                           |  13 MB  00:00:00
(4/4):  base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                              | 6.1 MB  00:00:01
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-11 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependencies Resolved
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Package                                                 Arch                                              Version                                            Repository                                        Size
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
epel-release                                            noarch                                            7-11                                               extras                                            15 k
Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package
Total download size: 15 k
Installed size: 24 k
Downloading packages:
warning:  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/extras/packages/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm:  Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm is not installed
epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                                                  |  15 kB  00:00:00
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Importing GPG key 0xF4A80EB5:
Userid     : "CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
Fingerprint: 6341 ab27 53d7 8a78 a7c2 7bb1 24c6 a8a7 f4a8 0eb5
Package    : centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64 (installed)
From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Installing  : epel-release-7-11.noarch                                                                                                                                                                         1/1
Verifying   : epel-release-7-11.noarch                                                                                                                                                                         1/1
Installed:
epel-release.noarch 0:7-11
Complete!

`[root@ip-172-31-15-245 centos]# yum install nodejs`

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                          |  32 kB  00:00:00
* base: download.cf.centos.org
* epel: mirror.23m.com
* extras: download.cf.centos.org
* updates: download.cf.centos.org
epel                                                                                                                                                                                          | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
(1/3):  epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                                | 1.0 MB  00:00:00
(2/3):  epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                                                                  |  96 kB  00:00:00
(3/3):  epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                | 7.0 MB  00:00:00
No package nodejs available.
Error: Nothing to do

Does anyone else experience the same issue?
Tried using nvm but does suit me so I'm looking for any advice?
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other users have been having problems with EPEL and Node.js on CentOS 7. Can you download the tarball and try to install it manually (I would use the default user's account instead of `root`, though):

**NOTE** - Tested on CentOS 7.9

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v17.4.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -P /home/<default user>/Downloads
cd /home/<default user>/Downloads
sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node*.tar.gz
```

Comment: Interesting, I have tried this approach before posting here but using the root account and it didn't work, I gave up on this.
Thank you for your response and pointing me to the right direction. This works great when executed on the default user.
Edit: In meantime I checked yum install nodejs and now it works.